# Is it possible to display banner ad using "adtapsy" in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Interstitial ad is working fine in iOS. 
But is it possible to display banner ad using "adtapsy"??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AdTapsy supports interstitial ads only for now.
You can still use AdMob banners in a combination with AdTapsy for interstitials. Note that since AdMob SDK is included in AdTapsy, in order to show banner ads you just need to make your own initialization of AdMob banner.

Comment: No i want to implement using AdTapsy only. Is it possible then?

Comment: Hi Nikita, I am co-founder of AdTapsy. This is not possible for now, I will forward this to the team.

Comment: It will be great if u people can implement for banner ad too

Comment: I want to use only Admob and imob in my project using AdTapsy. So other framework is useless for me. Please tell me how to delete other framework?

Comment: Hi Borislav, Please tell me is it possible to give support of iAd in AdTapsy?

Comment: Hi Nikita, we cannot commit with date, if you are registered on our website, you will receive notification when we release the support for iAd.